# Angular ng-model ng-selected

Tags: angularjs, model, angularjs-ng-repeat, selected

I want to bind a model value to selected item

```
<select id="hours" ng-model="v.T_Hour">
    <option ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(24) track by $index" ng-selected="{{$index==v.T_Hour}}" value="{{$index}}">{{$index>9?$index:"0"+$index}}:00</option>
</select>
```

I want after the page loads , the value of the model 'v.T_Hour' to be selected in select , i assign the value of the model in the controller, when i view the resulting HTML i see that the value is selected in the HTML code ,but not selected in the select control , and the select control displays an empty item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<select                                                      
    name="name" 
    id="id" 
    ng-options="option.name for option in v.data track by option.value" 
    ng-model="v.selected" 
    class="form-control inline-forms">
    <option value="" selected>{{placeHolder}}</option>
</select>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.v = {data:[], selected:{}, placeHolder:""}
$scope.v.data = [{name:"nameOne", value:"valueOne"},{name:"nameTwo", value:"valueTwo"},{name:"nameThree", value:"valueThree"}]
$scope.v.selected = $scope.v.data[0]
$scope.v.placeHolder = "Click to Select"
```

According Angular documentation ngOption is better way to go than ngRepeat:
Choosing between ngRepeat and ngOptions
In many cases, ngRepeat can be used on  elements instead of ngOptions to achieve a similar result. However, ngOptions provides some benefits:

more flexibility in how the 's model is assigned via the select as part of the comprehension expression
reduced memory consumption by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance
increased render speed by creating the options in a documentFragment instead of individually
Specifically, select with repeated options slows down significantly starting at 2000 options in Chrome and Internet Explorer / Edge.
see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: It works for ng-options but not for ng-repeat , i use ng-repeat to generate a list of day hours from 00:00 to 23:00 ,my select value comes from db , i assign v.T_Hour ="value from db" in my controller, but not working

Comment: Can you create a plunker to see the real case.